# Plugin to retaining image quality in website after resize or compress (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, plugins, image-resizing, image-compression

I'm developing a website using codeigniter that deals with images of high quality.

I have to compress and resize image with minimum quality loss and also i need to minimize its disk space. Is there any plugin which will help me out.

Please share your views.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://image.intervention.io/

It has a very sleek and easy API. As for compression, you're dependent on what's out there. jpeg compression seems to handle the job really well at about 70-80% quality

Answer (score 0):

Refer this, you will get good idea,

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Resizing in an external service is an option. There are lists of options available in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277571/is-there-a-cdn-which-provides-on-demand-image-resizing-cropping-sharpening-et